# How to set cloud_RoleName in Azure Container Instances?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-container-instances

We've deployed Azure Functions on Linux to an Azure Container Instance.

Unfortunately, the application insights logging is not displaying my `cloud_RoleName` at all using the default `ILogger`. In order to query logs by container, I need to set the `cloud_RoleName` to the name of the container image.

How can I set this telemetry property without having to use the Telemetry Client directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment) we managed to set the `cloud_RoleName` property by adding this environment variable to our ARM template in the `Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups` section in the ContainerProperties [EnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerinstance/2018-10-01/containergroups#environmentvariable-object) array:

```json
{
    "name": "WEBSITE_SITE_NAME",
    "value": "[parameters('containerGroups_name')]"
}
```

Now the logs in AppInsights contain the value set in the `WEBSITE_SITE_NAME` variable and we can easily query our logs as follows:

```
traces | where cloud_RoleName == "containerName"
```

This might also work for the `cloud_RoleInstance` by setting the `WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID` environment variable.